# Inject build timestamp into vue-cli build output files to verify deployments with yarn

Tags: vue.js, build, timestamp, yarnpkg, package.json

It is needed verify whether the latest build was deployed. I would like add timestamp on build log and in each file of the build output. I am using a Vue framework and yarn.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I needed to have a build timestamp in the output Vue app, not the logs.

(You could write to build logs by adding a `console.log(new Date().toIsoString())` in the webpack part of `vue.config.js`.)

One way to get the build timestamp into to the app itself is to make use of the fact that webpack uses a simple template language in the HTML itself.

In the Vue app `index.html` (for example), I inserted a data attribute on the root `<html>` element:

```
<html data-build-timestamp-utc="<%= new Date().toISOString() %>">
  ...
</html>
```

That's easily retrieved:

```
document.documentElement.dataset.buildTimestampUtc
```

You can then add that as a getter on the root `App` component, `@Provide` it to other components as "buildtime", etc.

This works on a main build as well as a development "serve" build - but remember the root HTML itself doesn't hot-module-reload, so although the build timestamp *is* being updated, you'll have to refresh the page to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use the ***define*** option.

```
let commonConfig =
{

  plugins: [vue()],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url))     
    },
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        nested: resolve(__dirname, 'auth_redirect.html')
      }
    }
  }
}

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode, ssrBuild }) => {
  
  if (command === 'serve')
  {
//
    return commonConfig;

  } 
  else 
  {
    commonConfig.define = {
      "BUILD_TIMESTAMP": new Date().toISOString()
      
    };

    // command === 'build'
    return commonConfig;
  }
})
```

And then you can just assign BUILD_TIMESTAMP to any javascript variable in your appCode.

`const buildNum = "BUILD_TIMESTAMP";//You will get right val in this`.

define has to be compatible with https://esbuild.github.io/api/#non-analyzable-imports so gives issues in serve mode. So I have used it conditionally in build mode only.
In Dev Mode you will see just raw value of buildNum variable.

Answer (score 0):

To explicit Andrew E answer on how to access the build date in the app:

- Add `data-build-timestamp-utc="<%= new Date().toISOString() %>"` into `<html>` element in index.html:
- To access it from within the app (Vue):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{ buildTimestampUTC }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            buildTimestampUTC: null,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        const htmlElement = document.documentElement;
        this.buildTimestampUTC = htmlElement.getAttribute('data-build-timestamp-utc');
    },
};
</script>
```